# what is the value of current and history in this code. please explain this

Tags: javascript, recursion

```js
function findSolution(target) {

// we didn't mentioned values of current and history then how can it
   takes the values of current and history?

  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
             find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
// → (((1 * 3) + 5) * 3)
```

// please explain the result

Answer (score 0):

Argument names are used to *create* variables. The values are defined when the function is called.

> ```
> function find(current, history) {
>
> return find(1, "1");
> ```

`current` is `1` and `history` is `"1"` (and they will have different values when they are called with different parameters in other parts of the program).